# "Unhandled page fault" error when executing a Windows application in Wine

Tags: windows, wine, winetricks

I'm trying to launch the [Shamela](https://shamela.ws/page/download) (المكتبة الشاملة) application in Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon which is a library for ebooks that use elastic search using Wine version: 8

This is what i get in terminal:

0024:fixme:netprofm:list_manager_GetConnectivity 03953308, 0395323C
0024:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0024:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (00020068,{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea},0): stub
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
006c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010030, 0): stub
006c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000190028, 0000000000010030): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00010058, 1): stub
0024:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00030072, 00010058): stub
0024:fixme:file:server_get_file_info Unsupported info class e
0024:fixme:file:server_get_file_info Unsupported info class e

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on write access to 00000045 at address 7BC26FC5 (thread 010c), starting debugger...
0114:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00010090, 1): stub
0114:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001009A, 00010090): stub
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0114:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0058:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset TCI failing on 20000000
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 20000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-gujr-extra\\aakar-medium.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-beng-extra\\Ani.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\malayalam\\Dyuthi-Regular.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\Gargi\\Gargi.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\Gubbi\\Gubbi.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-deva-extra\\kalimati.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\Navilu\\Navilu.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-telu-extra\\Pothana2000.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-gujr-extra\\Rekha.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-deva-extra\\samanata.ttf"
0024:fixme:font:find_matching_face Untranslated charset 255
0024:fixme:font:get_nearest_charset returning DEFAULT_CHARSET face->fs.fsCsb[0] = 00000000 file = L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\share\\fonts\\truetype\\fonts-telu-extra\\vemana2000.ttf"
0024:fixme:win:NtUserFlashWindowEx 0x50d594 - semi-stub
0024:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (DEADBEEF): stub
0024:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (6603AD3C) stub
0024:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (09D165D8) stub
pc@pc-HP-EliteBook-2560p:~$
```

And a get a dialog box:

```
Program error
The program cmd.exe has encountred a serious problem and needs to close
```

When i click show details this is what i get:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000045 in 32-bit code (0x7bc26fc5).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7bc26fc5 ESP:00791a30 EBP:01000000 EFLAGS:00010212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:00004130 EBX:0103b8e0 ECX:00720072 EDX:00000041
 ESI:010002b0 EDI:0103fa10
Stack dump:
0x00791a30:  00410025 00250020 00200041 00410025
0x00791a40:  00250020 00200041 00410025 00250020
0x00791a50:  00200041 00410025 00250020 00200041
0x00791a60:  0104fff8 00001002 0103f8f0 00000128
0x00791a70:  00250020 00200041 00410025 00791aa0
0x00791a80:  01000000 00000000 00791b08 01000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7bc26fc5 list_remove+0x13(elem=<internal error>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\include\wine\list.h:100] in ntdll (0x01000000)
  1 0x7bc26fc5 heap_free_block+0xf5(heap=01000000, flags=0x1002, block=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:778] in ntdll (0x01000000)
  2 0x7bc27dd4 RtlFreeHeap+0x10f(handle=<couldn't compute location>, flags=<couldn't compute location>, ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:506] in ntdll (0x00791b08)
  3 0x7bc2917a RtlFreeHeap+0x35(handle=<couldn't compute location>, flags=<couldn't compute location>, ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:1573] in ntdll (0x00791b48)
  4 0x6aaf4032 msvcrt_heap_free+0x4a(ptr=<internal error>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\heap.c:114] in ucrtbase (0x00791b78)
  5 0x6aaf4032 free+0x5d(ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\heap.c:413] in ucrtbase (0x00791b78)
  6 0x0041e6be WCMD_execute+0x67e(command=L"SET newparams=!newparams! !current!", redirects=L"", cmdList=00791E80, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1647] in cmd (0xfffffff6)
  7 0x0041d3a4 WCMD_process_commands+0x64(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0x1, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x00000003)
  8 0x00403be8 WCMD_part_execute+0x168(cmdList=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>, firstcmd=<is not available>, isIF=0x1, executecmds=0x1) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:1573] in cmd (0x010121b0)
  9 0x0040fdb0 WCMD_if+0x60(p=L""x%A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %", cmdList=00792240) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:2932] in cmd (0x0000000e)
  10 0x0041ebcf WCMD_execute+0xb8f(command=L"IF "x!newparams!" NEQ "x" ", redirects=L"", cmdList=00792240, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1637] in cmd (0x0000000e)
  11 0x0041d3a4 WCMD_process_commands+0x64(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0x1, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x00000002)
  12 0x00403be8 WCMD_part_execute+0x168(cmdList=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>, firstcmd=<is not available>, isIF=0x1, executecmds=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:1573] in cmd (0x01011f30)
  13 0x0040fdb0 WCMD_if+0x60(p=L""N" == "Y" ", cmdList=00792600) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:2932] in cmd (0x0000000e)
  14 0x0041ebcf WCMD_execute+0xb8f(command=L"IF "!silent!" == "Y" ", redirects=L"", cmdList=00792600, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1637] in cmd (0x0000000e)
  15 0x0041d3a4 WCMD_process_commands+0x64(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0xffffffff)
  16 0x0040128c WCMD_batch+0x17c(file=<is not available>, command=<is not available>, called=<is not available>, startLabel=<is not available>, pgmHandle=<is not available>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\batch.c:96] in cmd (0x00000000)
  17 0x0041da5f WCMD_run_program+0x5ef(command=L""Z:\media\pc\01D93B76FB51C4C0\shamela_4\elastic\bin\elasticsearch.bat"", called=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1204] in cmd (0x00792b54)
  18 0x0041e981 WCMD_execute+0x941(command=L""Z:\media\pc\01D93B76FB51C4C0\shamela_4\elastic\bin\elasticsearch.bat"", redirects=L"", cmdList=0079B320, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1644] in cmd (0x0000002f)
  19 0x0041d3a4 WCMD_process_commands+0x64(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0xffffffff)
  20 0x0041f8e4 wmain+0x994(argc=<couldn't compute location>, argvW=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2674] in cmd (0x0079fef8)
  21 0x00420ac8 wmainCRTStartup+0x68() [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\crt_wmain.c:60] in cmd (0x0079ff30)
  22 0x7b629ee0 in kernel32 (+0x29ee0) (0x0079ff48)
  23 0x7bc5c5a7 in ntdll (+0x5c5a7) (0x0079ff5c)
  24 0x7bc5cdb0 RtlCreateUserThread(entry=00420A60, arg=7FFD1000) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\thread.c:306] in ntdll (0x0079ffec)
0x7bc26fc5 heap_free_block+0xf5 [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:778] in ntdll: movl    %ecx,0x4(%edx)
Unable to access file 'Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c'
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (31 modules)
PE  00400000-00596000   Dwarf-4         cmd
PE  64a80000-64ad8000   Deferred        win32u
PE  65680000-656bd000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  66080000-66179000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  66640000-6665a000   Deferred        version
PE  667c0000-66805000   Deferred        shcore
PE  67500000-67553000   Deferred        imm32
PE  68880000-68d6a000   Deferred        user32
PE  69840000-6993a000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  6aac0000-6ad9c000   Dwarf-4         ucrtbase
PE  6bbc0000-6bc57000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6da80000-6dc9f000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  71400000-720ae000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7b000000-7b52c000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b759000   Dwarf-4         kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bebc000   Dwarf-4         ntdll
ELF 7d000000-7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e595000-7e59f000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7e59f000-7e5cf000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e5cf000-7e61f000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e61f000-7e642000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF 7e642000-7e660000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e660000-7e6a0000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7e6a0000-7e76d000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e76d000-7e875000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7e88b000-7e9ff000   Deferred        win32u.so
ELF 7e9ff000-7eb87000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7bb4000-f7c62000   Deferred        ntdll.so
ELF f7d62000-f7f97000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7f99000-f7fa7000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF f7faf000-f7fe7000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000020 shamela.exe
    00000024    0     
    00000104    0     
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000004c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000078    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000c8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000e0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0     
    00000054    0     
    00000058    0     wine_sechost_service
    0000005c    0     
    00000060    0     
    00000064    0     
    000000d4    0     
00000068 explorer.exe
    0000006c    0     
    00000094    0     
    00000098    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
00000070 winedevice.exe
    00000074    0     
    0000007c    0     
    00000080    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000084    0     
    00000088    0     
    0000008c    0     
    00000090    0     
    000000ac    0     
000000a4 plugplay.exe
    000000a8    0     
    000000b4    0     
    000000b8    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000bc    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000c0 svchost.exe
    000000c4    0     
    000000cc    0     
    000000d0    0     wine_sechost_service
000000d8 rpcss.exe
    000000dc    0     
    000000e4    0     
    000000e8    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000ec    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
000000fc conhost.exe
    00000100    0     
00000108 (D) C:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe
    0000010c    0 <== 
    00000118    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-8.0
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.15.0-60-generic
```

edit:
after installing "libgl1-mesa-glx":
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
export WINEDEBUG=+loaddll,+module
the first errors disappeared:
01a4:err:wgl:init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

---

and then i get this:
01a4:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load libvulkan.so.1.

i did this:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update

i've installed mesa-vulkan-drivers from synaptic manager
and then:
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386

so the problem diappears.
and a get a dialog box: program error
the program cmd.exe has encountred a serious problem and nneds to close
when i click show details this is what i get:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000045 in 32-bit code (0x7bc270db).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7bc270db ESP:007919f0 EBP:00791a58 EFLAGS:00010202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:00004130 EBX:0103b8e0 ECX:00000041 EDX:00720072
 ESI:010002b0 EDI:0103f8e8
Stack dump:
0x007919f0:  00410025 00250020 00200041 00410025
0x00791a00:  00250020 00200041 00410025 00250020
0x00791a10:  00200041 00410025 00250020 0103f8f0
0x00791a20:  0104fff8 00001002 01000000 00410025
0x00791a30:  00250020 00200041 00410025 00791a60
0x00791a40:  01000000 00000000 00791ac8 01000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7bc270db list_remove+0x9(elem=<internal error>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\include\wine\list.h:100] in ntdll (0x00791a58)
  1 0x7bc270db heap_free_block+0xeb(heap=01000000, flags=0x1002, block=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:780] in ntdll (0x00791a58)
  2 0x7bc28025 RtlFreeHeap+0x110(handle=<couldn't compute location>, flags=<couldn't compute location>, ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:508] in ntdll (0x00791ac8)
  3 0x7bc2938a RtlFreeHeap+0x35(handle=<couldn't compute location>, flags=<couldn't compute location>, ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:1608] in ntdll (0x00791b08)
  4 0x6aaf4382 msvcrt_heap_free+0x4a(ptr=<internal error>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\heap.c:114] in ucrtbase (0x00791b38)
  5 0x6aaf4382 free+0x5d(ptr=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\heap.c:413] in ucrtbase (0x00791b38)
  6 0x0041f756 WCMD_execute+0x706(command=L"SET newparams=!newparams! !current!", redirects=L"", cmdList=00791E50, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1647] in cmd (0x00791df8)
  7 0x0041e323 WCMD_process_commands+0x63(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0x1, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x00791e48)
  8 0x00403d10 WCMD_part_execute+0x170(cmdList=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>, firstcmd=<is not available>, isIF=0x1, executecmds=0x1) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:1573] in cmd (0x00791ea8)
  9 0x004104da WCMD_if+0x5a(p=L""x%A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %A %", cmdList=00792220) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:2932] in cmd (0x00791f18)
  10 0x0041fcc3 WCMD_execute+0xc73(command=L"IF "x!newparams!" NEQ "x" ", redirects=L"", cmdList=00792220, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1637] in cmd (0x007921c8)
  11 0x0041e323 WCMD_process_commands+0x63(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0x1, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x00792218)
  12 0x00403d10 WCMD_part_execute+0x170(cmdList=<register EBX not accessible in this frame>, firstcmd=<is not available>, isIF=0x1, executecmds=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:1573] in cmd (0x00792278)
  13 0x004104da WCMD_if+0x5a(p=L""N" == "Y" ", cmdList=007925F0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\builtins.c:2932] in cmd (0x007922e8)
  14 0x0041fcc3 WCMD_execute+0xc73(command=L"IF "!silent!" == "Y" ", redirects=L"", cmdList=007925F0, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1637] in cmd (0x00792598)
  15 0x0041e323 WCMD_process_commands+0x63(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x007925e8)
  16 0x0040129b WCMD_batch+0x17b(file=<is not available>, command=<is not available>, called=<is not available>, startLabel=<is not available>, pgmHandle=<is not available>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\batch.c:96] in cmd (0x00792648)
  17 0x0041ea29 WCMD_run_program+0x639(command=L""Z:\media\pc\01D93B76FB51C4C0\shamela_4\elastic\bin\elasticsearch.bat"", called=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1204] in cmd (0x0079b018)
  18 0x0041fa63 WCMD_execute+0xa13(command=L""Z:\media\pc\01D93B76FB51C4C0\shamela_4\elastic\bin\elasticsearch.bat"", redirects=L"", cmdList=0079B320, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:1644] in cmd (0x0079b2c8)
  19 0x0041e323 WCMD_process_commands+0x63(thisCmd=<is not available>, oneBracket=0, retrycall=0) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2383] in cmd (0x0079b318)
  20 0x00420a14 wmain+0x994(argc=<couldn't compute location>, argvW=<couldn't compute location>) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\programs\cmd\wcmdmain.c:2674] in cmd (0x0079fef8)
  21 0x00421c88 wmainCRTStartup+0x68() [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\msvcrt\crt_wmain.c:60] in cmd (0x0079ff30)
  22 0x7b62a2f0 in kernel32 (+0x2a2f0) (0x0079ff48)
  23 0x7bc5d037 in ntdll (+0x5d037) (0x0079ff5c)
  24 0x7bc5d840 RtlCreateUserThread(entry=00421C20, arg=7FFD1000) [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\thread.c:306] in ntdll (0x0079ffec)
0x7bc270db heap_free_block+0xeb [Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c:780] in ntdll: movl    %edx,0x4(%ecx)
Unable to access file 'Z:\usr\src\packages\BUILD\dlls\ntdll\heap.c'
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (31 modules)
PE  00400000-00597000   Dwarf-4         cmd
PE  64a80000-64ad8000   Deferred        win32u
PE  65680000-65903000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  66080000-66179000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  66640000-6665b000   Deferred        version
PE  667c0000-66806000   Deferred        shcore
PE  67500000-67553000   Deferred        imm32
PE  68880000-68d6e000   Deferred        user32
PE  69840000-6993c000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  6aac0000-6ada4000   Dwarf-4         ucrtbase
PE  6bbc0000-6bc59000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6da80000-6dcaa000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  71400000-720b7000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7b000000-7b52e000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b75b000   Dwarf-4         kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bec2000   Dwarf-4         ntdll
ELF 7d000000-7d005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7e59e000-7e5ce000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e5ce000-7e61e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e61e000-7e641000   Deferred        libbrotlicommon.so.1
ELF 7e641000-7e65f000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e65f000-7e69f000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7e69f000-7e76c000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e76c000-7e874000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7e88b000-7e9ff000   Deferred        win32u.so
ELF 7e9ff000-7eb87000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7b05000-f7b0f000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF f7b0f000-f7bbd000   Deferred        ntdll.so
ELF f7cbd000-f7ef2000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7ef5000-f7f03000   Deferred        libbrotlidec.so.1
ELF f7f0b000-f7f43000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio    name (all IDs are in hex)
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0     
    00000040    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    0000004c    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    00000078    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000b0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000c8    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
    000000e0    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0     
    00000054    0     
    00000058    0     wine_sechost_service
    0000005c    0     
    00000060    0     
    00000064    0     
    000000d4    0     
00000068 winedevice.exe
    0000006c    0     
    0000007c    0     
    00000080    0     wine_sechost_service
    00000084    0     
    00000088    0     
    0000008c    0     
    00000090    0     
    000000ac    0     
00000070 explorer.exe
    00000074    0     
    00000094    0     
    00000098    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000a4 plugplay.exe
    000000a8    0     
    000000b4    0     
    000000b8    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000bc    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
000000c0 svchost.exe
    000000c4    0     
    000000cc    0     
    000000d0    0     wine_sechost_service
000000d8 rpcss.exe
    000000dc    0     
    000000e4    0     
    000000e8    0     wine_sechost_service
    000000ec    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f0    0     wine_rpcrt4_server
    000000f4    0     wine_rpcrt4_io
000000fc conhost.exe
    00000100    0     
00000104 shamela.exe
    00000108    0     
    0000010c    0     
00000110 (D) C:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe
    00000114    0 <== 
    00000120    0     
System information:
    Wine build: wine-8.1
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.15.0-60-generic
```

Comment: `Unhandled page fault` is a generic error, telling that access to a memory address failed, but not why. Shamela isn't in [WineHQ App DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/), but [search](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=shamela) returns a couple of pages of problem reports. One dev has tried to repro one of them, unsuccessful likely due to language barrier. The easiest way to use it on Linux would probably be installing it on a Windows Virtual Machine.

Comment: i have updated the wine to version 8 and the new error code is in the question. i hope that you can help

Comment: For future reference; if you change something and results after change are different; I'd recommend not to remove previous results, just add to the question instead. For example in the original you stated something about installing missing DLLs, which can very well be related to the issues. Googling the messages I get a lot of results including issues with NVIDIA etc. I'd second Artemis's recommendation - you should drop this to WineHQ. Please note that exact Wine version is important.

Answer (score 1):

Windows applications are **not** guaranteed to work under Wine. First you need to check whether the application works in Wine 8.1, if it doesn't, you could file a bug report here: https://bugs.winehq.org/ - however if it's not popular enough there's very little chance Wine developers will fix it any time soon. Wine is primarily developed by CodeWeavers and their focus is on their commercial clients and business partners such as Valve.